# How do i fix Blazor webassembly 3.2.0 preview 2 update issue in app.razor?

Tags: blazor

I have updated my Blazor web assembly app to the latest 3.2.0 preview 2 and I cannot resolve this error in App.razor

Error is pretty straightforward, NewLayout1 cannot be found. It exists, it inherits LayoutComponentBase but for some reason App.razor doesn't see it.

What can I do to fix this?

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(NewLayout1)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(NewLayout1)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

> The type or namespace name 'NewLayout1' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because
>   some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible
>   to the delegate return type\Debug\netstandard2.1\Razor\App.razor.g.cs

```
__builder.AddAttribute(2, "Found", (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteData>)((routeData) => (__builder2) => {
                __builder2.AddMarkupContent(3, "\r\n        ");
                __builder2.OpenComponent<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteView>(4);
                __builder2.AddAttribute(5, "RouteData", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteData>(
#nullable restore
#line 3 "C:\Users\Source\Repos\Admin.Blazor.Client\Admin.UI\Client\App.razor"
                               routeData

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                ));
                __builder2.AddAttribute(6, "DefaultLayout", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<System.Type>(
#nullable restore
#line 3 "C:\Users\\Source\Repos\Admin.Blazor.Client\Admin.UI\Client\App.razor"
                                                          typeof(NewLayout1)

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                ));
                __builder2.CloseComponent();
                __builder2.AddMarkupContent(7, "\r\n    ");
            }
            ));
```

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60881628/system-invalidoperationexception-client-27marchtemplate-client-not-found

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891885/blazor-server-side-projects-no-longer-log-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the namespace of `NewLayout1` ?

Try setting`@namespace Admin.UI` in your `NewLayout1` component.

And make sure `@using Admin.UI` is set in `_Imports.razor`

Comment: I noticed that now build action has to be set to Content on NewLayout1 in order for app.razor to recognize it

Comment: Ok, isn't that default?