# Blazor server side projects no longer log in

Tags: authentication, blazor, http2

I have a number of Blazor test projects all of which were working correctly until a few days ago. Now none of them will login and give the following error:

This site can’t be reached
The web page at https://localhost:44373/Identity/Account/Login might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Visual studio throws no error and there is no error in the browser console. (Tested on Edge, Chrome, Opera & Firefox)

I have subsequently created a new default Blazor app and it has the same problem.

Visual Studio 2019 16.5.1
.Net core 3.1.3 with all NuGet packages updated to latest 3.1.3 versions

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60881628/system-invalidoperationexception-client-27marchtemplate-client-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar conversation on this very topic in `aspnet/aspnetcore` GitHub repository, where it turned out to be an OS-specific issue.
In that particular case the user was using a preview version of Windows 10, and after switching to the latest release version, things started to work.

Here is the conversation: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20105#issuecomment-603839404

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am on the insider program, so this could well be the cause. I will see if any updates are available to fix. Many Thanks.

Comment: The last comment on that thread suggests, that it was fixed on the latest Insider build too: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20105#issuecomment-604744232I

Comment: Apparently fixed in 19595 but I am currently only eligible for 19592. Going to have to wait a week or so. They are pretty frequent. Many thanks again.

Comment: It would be great, if you could mark this as an answer, if you feel I did answer your original question.

Comment: Although 19592 fixes the login problem, there are still other IIS Server issues within Visual Studio which presumably require 19595 to fix.